# input type='color' fields saving as an array in database but not populating input type ='color' 'value attribute'

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

input type='color' fields saving as an array in database but not populating input type ='color' 'value attribute'

I am trying this but not working.

```
label(for='firstColor') Color 1
input#firstColor(type='color' name='colors' value = colors)
label(for='secondColor') Color 2
input#secondColor(type='color' name='colors' value = colors)
label(for='thirdColor') Color 3
input#thirdColor(type='color' name='colors' value = colors)
```

I am receiving this data from database:

```
{colors: Array(3)
  0: "#f50000"
  1: "#000000"
  2: "#000000"
 }
```

And using this code to populate:

```
 $.each(results, function (i,v){
        form.find('[name="'+i+'"]').val(v);
    })
```

but no success in populating input color value.

PS: multiple checkboxes, multiple select options working fine using same setup above.

Finally solved it by updating code:

```
 var form = $('#registerForm');
    $.each(results, function (i,v){
        if(i == 'colors'){
        $.each(results.colors, function (a,b){
            $('[name="colors['+a+']"]').val(b);
           
        })
        }else{
        form.find('[name="'+i+'"]').val(v);
    }
    })
```

I still want to know how it was working without updating code on multiple checkbox and multiple select but not on multiple color inputs?

Comment: If you want I can share complete process but I am looking for logic only

Answer (score 0):

If its for a HTML Page, storing the #RRGGBB tag as a string is probably enough.

If its for .NET , it supports building a color from its ARGB Value

```
System.Drawing.Color c = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(int);

int x = c.ToArgb();
```

so you could just store that int.

Comment: I am using HTML but its not working for me. I have updated my question above please check. @marmik